# How to count the up and downs

Tags: discrete-signals

I want to count the threads of a bolt in an image. My solution is this:

- capture an image
- Find the bolt
- Get one dimentional data from it's top to bottom
- Find the thread count from signal

This is the bolt with a red line specifying where the samples are being picked:
[image]

And this is the generated signal from pixels in the image:
[image]

**How can I get thread counts from this signal?**

**How can I find the threads part?**

Comment: Conceptually, this question and [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/53890/how-to-count-the-number-of-threads-in-a-nut-using-image-processing) are similar. Therefore, I would suggest that we keep one and talk about the variations in the "counting" process. Also please keep in mind that you are going to have to talk a bit more about your lighting and if you are not doing it already you are going to have to control the imaging conditions very much to ensure a consistent result.

Comment: Thanks. I combined two questions and will delete this question soon